# Cocos2d-x or Moai sdk?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, coronasdk, moai

Hi as a 6 month corona sdk game developer I wanted to move to something more powerful and also multi platform,for a long run.
**Cocos 2d-x or Moai?**

And just to be in my shoes you have to know,I already know lua(still improving) ,and I am looking for multi platform
sdk?
so moai would be my choice,but there is so little documentation on it. 
cocos2d-x the negative part would be I have to learn a new language and ,there is no major book and tutorial on cocos2d-x  either.
A.Do you think moai sdk is as powerful as cocos2d-x?and if not why?

B.with my new background in game development,I am getting conformable with lua more and more,
how can I make myself efficent in moai development ,how can I master its workflow,what are my sources,what do you recommend for learning moai sdk?

C.the other problem I have with learning cocos2d-x is you have to refer back to books that have been written in objective-c,is it possible to learn c++ and just jump into learning cocos2d-x?

and believe me I have spent weeks searching the web and all the internet for these specific answers,so I would appreciate if you share your point of view with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question will probably be closed, because it's not a very good fit for Stack Overflow's format. But as long as you're here:

If you don't already know C, Objective-C or C++, you're in for a world of hurt. Lua is orders of magnitude simpler. Take a look at [hello world for Cocos 2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_2_-_How_to_Add_a_sprite). I've coded in C and C++ for 15+ years, but do almost all my current development in dynamic languages or at least garbage collected languages (Java, C#). I'm just more productive.

MOAI is a very powerful platform, and it's in it's infancy. Several studios have already released games with it, and Double Fine (Tim Schafer) just chose it for their 3+ million dollar Double Fine Adventure (targeting iOS, Android, PC, Mac and Linux). It's open source, so they stuff these studios find lacking they *add*, and the platform just gets better.

As for learning, check out MOAI's wiki, look at all the sample code, read the forums and/or ask questions on the forums. It's definitely a bit of a learning curve, especially coming from Corona, but far less than learning C++ and Cocos 2D-x.

Comment: if doesn't including the licensing, i guess Maoi is better for him. But Maoi requires to display a screen for at least 2 seconds to show Maoi Logo, which Most Studio don't want. On the other hand, cocos2d-x MIT have more freedom. At least our company choose cocos2d-x other than Maoi. But for a independent developer, I recommend Maoi.

Comment: Thanks,It is my first time here,I make sure I will create better questions in the future.

Comment: I was planning to include them in the credits,I read that is enough as well.

Comment: Cocos2D-X has scripting support with both Lua and Javascript.